# How to Compress/Zip a directory(with files) without creating directories from my file system ?

Tags: directory, zip, php-ziparchive

I have problems with ZipArchive that compresses a directory of files. Most of the samples from the internet is easy to understand and it work EXCEPT that when I look at the zip result of my zipping process. My zip file creates folders based from my filesytem directory.

> For example:

C > workspace > myproject > temp > ziptest > (files....)

When it should suppose to contain only a folder that starts with "ziptest" as the parent folder of my zipfile. Can anyone help me with this. How do I get rid of unecessary folders that have been created in my zip file.

**My code looks like this:**

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($zipFile, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($tempFile));
foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
  $zip->addFile(realpath($key), $key);
}
$zip->close();
```